# How to get reactive data in to Radiant in a shiny application

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny app that I would like to use some of the Radiant functions in. I have a dataset (which is reactive) already in the `[shiny][1]` app and I would like this to be loaded as the default instead of the `diamonds` dataset. Is there a simple way to do this? I guess I would have to do something like `input$dataset<-RV$data` where `RV$data` is the default dataset I want. But where would I put this code?

I looked at the `global.R` code where the datasets are initialised and this seems to detect stored files:

```
df_names <- getOption("radiant.init.data", default = c("diamonds", "titanic"))
  for (dn in df_names) {
    if (file.exists(dn)) {
      df <- load(dn) %>% get()
      dn <- basename(dn) %>%
        {gsub(paste0(".", tools::file_ext(.)), "", ., fixed = TRUE)}
    } else {
      df <- data(list = dn, package = "radiant.data", envir = environment()) %>% get()
      r_info[[paste0(dn, "_lcmd")]] <- glue::glue('{dn} <- data({dn}, package = "radiant.data", envir = environment()) %>% get()\nregister("{dn}")')
    }
    env[[dn]] <- df
    if (!bindingIsActive(as.symbol(dn), env = env)) {
      makeReactiveBinding(dn, env = env)
    }
    r_info[[paste0(dn, "_descr")]] <- attr(df, "description")
  }
  r_info[["datasetlist"]] <- basename(df_names)
  r_info[["url"]] <- NULL
  r_info
}
```

However, because the data files are created after the shiny app has been started, I dont think this part of the code is relevant as it is just preloading the app with default datasets.

I then tried to see if I could add datasets to `r_info`.

There must be a straightforward way of loading reactive datasets that already exist in a shiny app without having to download them and then re-upload them using the `Radiant` part of the app?..

Comment: Hi Sebastian, what do you mean by the "Radiant part of the app"? Radiant seems like a standalone shiny application.  All I see of using pieces of it is [here](https://radiant-rstats.github.io/radiant/articles/programming.html)

Comment: I meant the radiant part of my app. Ie once I have integrated radiant into an app.

Comment: That's what I'm not understanding. As far as I can tell, the Radiant app is not designed for integration in to existing shiny apps. If you want to do what Radiant does in your app, you'd use the functions I linked.